# Workaround to using multiple unions?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Is there is a way to avoiding using the below multiple unions through a single query or multiple query under one run?

Access raises a "too many fields" error.

```
SELECT *
FROM  FILES f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 

               FROM Networks
               WHERE  (f.Network_ID = Networks.Network_ID) AND 
                             (f.[009_Network] = Networks.Network_Code))
 UNION
 SELECT *
 FROM  FILES f
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 

               FROM    LINE
               WHERE  (f.[LINE1_ID] = LINE.[LINE_ID]) AND  
                             (f.[Line 1] = LINE.[Line_Code]))
UNION
SELECT *
FROM  FILES f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 

               FROM    Transportation_Mode
               WHERE  (f.[Trans_ID] = Transportation_Mode.[Trans_ID]) AND 
                             (f.[Transportation_Mode] = Transportation_Mode.[Mode]))
UNION
SELECT *
FROM  FILES f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 

               FROM    DISCIPLINE
               WHERE  (f.[Discipline_ID] = DISCIPLINE.[DIS_ID]) AND
                             (f.[012_Discipline] = DISCIPLINE.[Dis Code]))
```

Comment: The 255 column limit includes the other selects. Consider selecting only needed columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could get the same functionality by using

`SELECT DISTINCT * ...` `...WHERE NOT EXISTS ([Select Statement] OR NOT EXISTS [Second Select Statement] OR NOT EXISTS...;)`

However, that would not fix the error you are having with `Access`. There are hard limits to how many records and `Access` table can have, so you may have to split up your data across multiple tables in this instance.

The `recordset` limit for an `Access` `query` is 1 gigbyte.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "Left Join" or "Inner Join" to link multiples tables.

```
Select * from FILES1 f1 
LEFT JOIN FILES2 f2
   ON f1.ID = f2.ID;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: If you have 2 tables with 1 row in each and 2 columns, join will give you 1 row and 4 columns if you do select *. Union, on the other hand, will give you 2 rows and 2 columns. Join != Union.

Comment: The thing is that I'm trying to figure out if there is a value in table 1 that hasn't been defined in the other tables. Basically table 1 is only filled by values that comes from other tables, so I'm not searching matches.

Answer (score 0):

Left join?

```
SELECT *
  FROM (((Files f LEFT JOIN Networks net
        ON f.Network_ID = net.network_id AND ...)
       LEFT JOIN Line line
        ON f.line1_id = line.line_id AND ... )
       LEFT JOIN Transportation_Mode tmod
        ON f.trans_id = tmod.trans_id AND ... )
       LEFT JOIN DISCIPLINE disc
        ON f.Discipline_ID = disc.Discipline_ID AND ...
 WHERE net.network_id IS NULL
    OR line.line_id IS NULL
    OR tmod.trans_id IS NULL
    OR disc.Discipline_ID IS NULL;
```

For your other question...

> Access raises a "too many fields" error.

Try not selecting back all fields. The limit is something like 255 fields. Do you really need all 255?

Comment: MS Access SQL requires parentheses across multiple `JOIN` which you can easily do here.

Comment: Thank you so much! The thing is that I'm trying to figure out if there is a value in table 1 that hasn't been defined in the other tables. Basically table 1 is only filled by values that comes from other tables, so I'm not searching for blanks. Do you think the above code can be modified accordingly?

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM (((Files f LEFT JOIN Networks net
        ON f.Network_ID <> net.network_id AND ...) ?

Comment: If a value hasn’t been defined in another table, the records for that table return null. For example let’s say “Files” has a record with a “line1_id” of 2. If the “line” table does not have a record where “line_id” is 2, the joined records from “line” will be null in the resultset. You can then filter the results (with a where field is null) to only show “File” records with no matching “line”. If you join on inequality (what you proposed), you’ll may (depending on your data) match to a whole lot of records.